# Comparing values of Ruby XMLRPC datetime returned from API to normal Ruby DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I have an XMLRPC datetime returned from a remote API, and I want to perform normal comparison operations to a standard Ruby datetime object, such as >, <, >=, etc. I've read that XMLRPC has some strange datetime restrictions (such as it doesn't support values before or after a certain date) and using DateTime.parse() for the returned object doesn't work, with or without string interpolation.

How do you accurately convert an XMLRPC::DateTime object to a standard Ruby 2.2.2 DateTime object so I can execute comparisons, regardless of the date returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please convert everything into epoch_in_seconds

```
(XMLRPC::DateTime instance).to_time.to_i

(DateTime instance).to_i
```

You can also convert everything in UTC to make sure you're working with the same timezone